# What does it mean for a random variable to have finite second order moments?

Tags: probability, time-series

I'm trying to digest some litterature in time series analysis and don't quite understand what it means for a random variable to have finite second order moments. Tried to look it up in a probability theory textbook, however I don't quite get the intuition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a source? I suspect it means to have a finite variance, but I'm not sure.

Comment: P. J. Brockwell and R. A. Davis: Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting, Springer, Third Edition - under 2.5.1 "Prediction of second-order random variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $k$-th moment of a random variable $X$ is $E(X^k)$. We say that this moment exists if $E(|X|^k)$ is a finite value (note the absolute value). If a r.v. has a finite $K$-th moment, the moments $k \le K$ are also finite. This property comes from the fact that the probability of the universe, the whole probability space, is $1$ and can be further justified by the comment by James Martin below this answer.

The variance is $Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2 = E(X^2)-E(X^1)^2 $. By the definition above and the property, if $X$ has a finite 2nd order moment, it has a variance (and conversely).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this property comes from measure theory". If $0\leq k\leq K$ then $|X|^k \leq 1+|X|^K$, so $E(|X|^k)\leq 1+E(|X|^K)$.

Comment: Measure theory says that if the measure of the space is finite, then $L^q \subset L^p$ if $p \le q$. If a r.v. has a $k$-th moment, then it is $L^k$ with respect to the probability space. Your reasoning holds true because $E(1)=1$, which happens because in probability the measure of the whole space is $1$ (and thus finite). Anyway I will edit this sentence as it is probably not the best way to explain it in this particular case and I find yours better. @JamesMartin